# Найти первую должность работника через SQL-(под-)запрос

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Условие:

> Составить  запрос  к БД  HR.  Результат запроса должен содержать  две колонки.
> Первая  колонка  -  имя  и  фамилия  работника.  Вторая  колонка  –  первая
> должность,  которую  он  занял  при  поступлении  на  предприятие.  Указание:
> необходимо механизм вложенных запросов при построении предложения SQL.

В общем, я решил составить запрос, и внутри него - подзапрос, выводящий ту должность, на которую сотрудник пришёл раньше всего (т.е. всё согласно условию):

```sql
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       E.FIRST_NAME||' '||E.LAST_NAME EMP,
       J.JOB_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN
  (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
          JOB_ID,
          START_DATE
   FROM JOB_HISTORY) J ON (J.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID)
```

Однако, когда пытаюсь добавить условие WHERE, выбирающее самую раннюю дату (т.е. самую первая должность), выводится лишь одна должность, - которая стоит самой первой в списке, - и, следовательно, всё работает неправильно:

```sql
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME||' '||E.LAST_NAME EMP,
       J.JOB_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN
  (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
          JOB_ID,
          START_DATE
   FROM JOB_HISTORY A
   WHERE A.START_DATE =
       (SELECT MIN(START_DATE)
        FROM JOB_HISTORY)) J ON (J.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID)
```

Плюс ко всему, может быть, я вообще воюю не совсем туда, и подобный запрос надо реализовать иным образом (но как именно - не могу приложить ума).

Ниже показана структура тех двух таблиц, что джойнятся в самом запросе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не забывайте форматировать SQL, например с помощью https://sqlformat.org/

Comment: И тут явно не хватает таблицы HR_JOB чтобы получить наименование должности

Comment: @Anatoly отформатировал (+ перезалил изображение с использующимися таблицами)

Comment: *Указание: необходимо механизм вложенных запросов при построении предложения SQL.* Не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       employees.first_name || ' ' || employees.last_name emp,
       FIRST_VALUE(job_id) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY start_date) job_id
FROM employees 
JOIN job_history ON job_history.employee_id = employees.employee_id
```

Comment: Ох, спасибо большое. Решение работает, -- однако преподаватель-задира все равно будет требовать следовать методичке, -- и в работе с агрегатными функциями, и в работе с подзапросами:) Но дальше буду разбираться, т.к. понял принцип